# How can I check if the ID doesn't exist..?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am making a game for class and I decided to add a commenting system with the ability to report comments. I created a table called `comments` and a column within the table called `report_active`. When the user reports a comment the value in that column changes to 1. Then all comments with a 1 in the `active_report` column are listed in the adminCP.

There is a file called `comments.php` which lists all comments and allows users to add new ones. Next to each comment I added a report button which links to a file called `report_comment.php`. I used this file to run the update query.

That file looks like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('db_connect.php');
require_once('security.php');

if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $report_active = 1;
    $id = $_GET['id'];

    $update = $db->prepare("UPDATE comments set report_active = ? WHERE id = ?");
    $update->bind_param('ii', $report_active, $id);

    if ($update->execute()) {
        $_SESSION['reported'] = 'reported';
        header('Location: comments.php');
        die();
    }
} else {
    header('Location: comments.php');
}
 ?>
```

The session variable `$_SESSION['reported']` is what I used to determin whether to display an alert to the user which says Comment Reported, then I unset the session.

What I am asking is how can I check to see if an ID sent as a `$_GET` request actually exists and if it does then run the usual `$_SESSION['reported']` and if not then set a new session `$_SESSION['errorReport']` which then displays and error alert?

I have tried:

`if ($update->execute() && $update->num_rows) {` however this didn't work.

Is there another way for me to do this?

Comment: I apologize for not answering your question in advanced, but you really should rethink the architecture of your DB. It is a bad practice to be using flags to indicate relationships. You should use joins to join 2 tables and check if there are any rows that match to indicate whether a report is active or not. Please look up joins, foreign keys, and SQL relationships.

Comment: I just visited: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp. I agree that is a much better way of doing it. The reason I did it like this was because it is a small assignment, and I didn't feel the need to create multiple tables, when it isn't going to be used heavily. I will write about it though as an option for a bigger, public application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can execute your query as you do now and check if any rows were modified using <strike>[`rowCount()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)</strike> [`affected_rows`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php):

```
if ($update->execute()) {
  if ($update->affected_rows > 0)
  {
    $_SESSION['reported'] = 'reported';
    header('Location: comments.php');
    die();
  }
  else
  {
    // no row was modified / the ID does not exist.
  }
}
```

**Edit:** The original answer applies to PDO, for mysqli you would need [`$update->affected_rows`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php) instead.

Comment: Seems like OP is using `mysqli_*` --- `bind_param`